# Render Partial Vertically, div_for, partials collection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, collections, renderpartial

show.html.erb

```
<%= render :partial => "hello", :collection => hello %>
```

_hello.html.erb

```
<%= div_for hello do %>
  <%= link_to image_tag( hello.image, :size => "75x75"), '#' %>
  <%= hello.updated_at.strftime('%m/%d/%Y') %>
<% end %>
```

Currently outputs:

hello1

hello2

etc.

Desired Output:

hello1 hello2 hello3 hello4

hello5 hello6 hello7 hello8

etc.

Basically I want to render the item side by side in columns instead of one per a line.  I've tried using a table and I know how to float divs, but the problem I'm having is that rails generates the div class and id, and I don't know how to do this short of creating in the css file special rules for id1, id2, id3, id4, ...id200, etc.  I was wondering if their was an easier way to put a specific number of items on one line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a class to div_for, like this

```
<%= div_for(hello, :class => "SOMECLASS" do %>
  <%= link_to image_tag( hello.image, :size => "75x75"), '#' %>
  <%= hello.updated_at.strftime('%m/%d/%Y') %>
<% end %>
```

and then you can style the div with float:left, so that the divs will be side by side.